# How to use cookieSession in express

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm trying to use the built in `cookieSession` object of connect, but I cannot get it to work properly with express.

I have this app:

```
var express = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('whatever'));
  app.use(connect.cookieSession({ cookie: { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 }}));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('root');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sess' of undefined
    at Object.cookieSession [as handle]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any special reason you're using connect.cookieSession instead of express.cookieSession?

Comment: @AndersBornholm the question is pretty old, it was probably not available at that point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the version of your `connect` module? The `cookieSession` middleware was first added in version 2.0.0. Run `npm list|grep connect` to make sure your `connect` version is at least 2.0.0 or higher.

Comment: Express comes with connect 1.8.6, so yeah, that's probably why it's not working. Thanks

Comment: Express 3 comes with connect 2.7.

Answer (score 13):

Sessions won't work unless you have these 3 in this order:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession());
app.use(app.router);
```

Working like a charm after that.

see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10239147/2454820

Comment: I'm getting Error: `secret` option required for cookie sessions

Comment: Just add a secret:  app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:'mysecret'}));

Comment: Remove the `app.use(app.router)` and it worked for me. (also had to had to add the secret)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. Turned out that everyauth was amongst the modules linking with connect 1.7.5, after npm remove everyauth, all the issues where gone.