# 'session' is undefined when using express / redis for session store

Tags: session, node.js, redis, express

I'm trying to use redis for sessions in my express app.

I do the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

app.configure('development', function(){     
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "password", 
                            store: new RedisStore({
                                          host: "127.0.0.1",
                                          port: "6379",
                                          db: "mydb"
                                        })  
          }));
```

Later on, in my app, if i do something like:

```
var whatever = req.session.someProperty;
```

I get:

> Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined

This indicates that req.session is undefined
*(I can see this from a console.log entry in my config section)*

I've definitely got redis running, and can see my app connects to it initially (using redis-cli monitor)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you're missing:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

before your `app.use(express.session(...));` call.

See [here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html).

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I do have app.user(cookieParser()) thing

Answer (score 53):

Sessions won't work unless you have these 3 in this order:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
```

I'm not sure if router is mandatory to use sessions, but it breaks them if it's placed before them.

Comment: I had app.use(app.router); before express.session, which seems to break it.

Comment: this answer was hard to find, should be somewhere in the docs. Upvoted!

Comment: This answer is more complete. You need to do both things: 1) enable cookieParser() and 2) move 'app.use(app.router);' to the bottom. I think this should be the correct answer.

Comment: even with all 3 things in right order,req.session still undefined, do not know why.

Comment: Sir, I wish i could give you +2.  You solved a TON of my problems

Comment: Cheers.. !! Feeling nice to fix this.

Comment: How would this answer update since version 1.5.0? Currently, express-session is a separate module. According to the docs, "the cookie-parser middleware no longer needs to be used for this module to work"

Comment: I'm afraid I have to let someone else answer that. I abandoned node 5 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, however it was caused by changes in the latest version of express.

You now need to pass express-session to the function connect-redis exports to extend session.Store:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session')
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

Answer (score 4):

Things have changed recently with Express 3 / Express 4.
Please confirm you are using version **4**.

The complete middleware concept changed. You need to install these middlewares manually. "express-session" is one of the 4.0 middlewares.

I recommend to read

http://scotch.io/bar-talk/expressjs-4-0-new-features-and-upgrading-from-3-0 and https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Additionally some users were confused that the [github repo](https://github.com/expressjs/session) itself is named just "session" but

```
npm install express-session
```

is correct.

Comment: This question was asked Apr 17 2012, therefore NOT related to version 4

Comment: For version 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611920/session-using-nodejs-and-express-4-x-req-session-undefined

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It turned out that redis was simply configured to a different port.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. I tripped over the fact that Heroku changed the REDIS_URL that I was using on my localhost. I could have known this as they mention this themselves: > "the REDIS config vars may change at any time. Relying on the config var outside of your Heroku app may result in you having to re-copy the value if it changes" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#create-a-new-instance