# Using Session MemoryStore in Express.js does not define req.session

Tags: session, node.js, express

I have set up a Node.js test server with Express.js which looks like this:

```
var express     = require('express');
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;
var app         = express.createServer();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.session({
        store: new MemoryStore(),
        secret: 'secret',
        key: 'bla'
    }));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session);
    res.end("html");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Why does `console.log(req.session)` print out undefined? Didn't I use it correctly? What do I need to do in order to save variables to a user's session?

The client receives a SID which is stored as his cookie, but I cannot assign any attributes to `req.session`, because it is not defined. Thanks for any hints to solve this problem! :-)

This are the versions I'm using:

```
├─┬ express@2.5.9
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.7
│ │ └── formidable@1.0.9
│ ├── mime@1.2.4
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ └── qs@0.4.2
```

Comment: what version of express are you using?

Comment: does it work without using MemoryStore?

Comment: @mihai: Sorry for forgetting to mention the version - I have edited it into my posting now. @Jonathan: Leaving out the line `store: new MemoryStore(),` does not change anything. Sadly I don't have another session store which I could test if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `app.router` is but it seems to be the cause of the problem. Deleting that line made it work for me.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what kind of sorcery has put this line into my code. :D Thanks, removing it helps and my routes still work.

Comment: From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191692/session-is-undefined-when-using-express-redis-for-session-store
It appears that use(app.router) before express.session breaks it.. having it after works. FYI :)

Comment: @Linus G Thiel's answer below is more appropriate.

Answer (score 20):

Here's your problem: `app.use(app.router)` mounts your routes in that position in the call chain. You have it *before* your session middleware, so there is no `req.session` yet. When you leave it out, your routes will be positioned whenever you do your first `app.get` (or `app.post` and so on). If you still wish to control where your routes should be, you can just move `app.use(app.router)` below the session middleware.

See Express' [Configuration](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration) and [Middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware) documentation.

Comment: You are right, after removing it everything worked as expected. Your answer is of course as good as mihai's, but I accepted his one, because he was first. Thank you very much for this awesome explanation!! :-)