# undefined error in express js session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

i want save data in session params.

```
/* Modules */

/* App Settings */
// session settings
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
if(req.session.param){
    console.log('OK!');
}else{
    console.log('not found session data');
}
});

app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

when i run this codes

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'param' of undefined
at C:\Users\frknbasaran\campusca\app.js:25:16
```

Thanks in advance

Sessions won't work unless you have these 3 in this order:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: sounds like `req.session` is `undefined`

Comment: Why exactly would the session have a `param` key when you've set no such key? `req.session` holds session data, `req.params` is something else ?

Comment: Have you checked this question? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191692/session-is-undefined-when-using-express-redis-for-session-store/10239147

Comment: @Matias thanks guy! 
i solve my problem with these steps

Sessions won't work unless you have these 3 in this order:

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
app.use(app.router);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions won't work unless you have these 3 in this order:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
app.use(app.router);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it first... I did not see this in your code, something like:

```
req.session.param = "Hello World";
```

Unless `param` refers to the property that comes with the request object that only url variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set req.session.params, since its req.session which is none. What about cookieSession. That should give you req.session http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#cookieSession