# Redis Cloud for sessions in node heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have an express app that was using redis cloud to store sessions in Heroku. It was working fine a few months ago, but I have just revisited it and it is no longer working. It seems there is no session, and throws the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`, the offending line of code is

```
if (!req.session.user) {
...
...
}
```

Maybe I'm configuring things incorrectly

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var redis = require('redis-url').connect(config.redis_url);

var sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: config.redis_host,
        port: config.redis_port
    }),
    secret: 'Its a secret.',
    cookie: { secure: true },
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
});
```

The corresponding config file is

```
module.exports = {
    mongo_url: process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/psa',
    redis_url: process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL || 'redis://localhost:6379',
    redis_host: taken from process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL,
    redis_port: taken from process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL,
    port: process.env.PORT || 5000
};
```

This works locally `forman start web` when I define the session middleware as follows

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'VkWdLXauq6ya',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new RedisStore({
        client: redis
    }),
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 3600000
    },
    name: 'sessionCookie'
});
```

Comment: Are your Heroku add-ons still provisioned?

Comment: yes, I even created a new app to be sure

Comment: Hmmm - I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious but my Node-fu is so weak... time for the cavalry perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the cookieParser middleware? You'll need:

`app.use(express.cookieParser());`

Seems like it is similar to this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191692/session-is-undefined-when-using-express-redis-for-session-store).

Comment: cavalry arrives promptly :)

Comment: same problem, I'm using cookieParser

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the created session middleware? eg:

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
```

That creates a Function that can be used in your express stack. However, it does nothing until you actually use it, like:

```
var app = express();
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
```