# Session using NodeJS and Express 4.x (req.session undefined)

Tags: node.js, session, express, authentication

First of all sorry my bad English. I'm studying and I'm doing an academic project and came across a problem. I can not recall a session variable.

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.7.0",
    "ejs": "~1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.8.7",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "ini": "^1.3.4",
    "mysql": "^2.8.0",
    "winston": "^1.0.1"
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
...
require('./router/main')(app, language, connection, logger);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'pecuniamsekretsession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

main.js

```
module.exports = function(app, languageItems, connection, logger) {
    app.post('/', require('../router/login.js')(languageItems, connection, logger)); 
    app.get('/', require('../router/login.js')(languageItems, connection, logger));
}
```

login.js

```
module.exports = function (language, connection, logger) {

    var routerTemplateLogin = function (req, res) {
        var utils = require('../utils/utils');
        var util = new utils.Util;  

        // It does not work  :-(
        logger.debug(req.session); 

        req.on('data', function(data) {
            var arrayPost = util.postDataToArray(data);
        });     

        res.render('pages/login.ejs', {
            lang: language
        });
    }

    return routerTemplateLogin;
}
```

In login.js see `// It does not work  :-(`. Full project in https://github.com/braulioti/pecuniam

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to move `require('./router/main')(app, language, connection, logger);` below your `app.use(session({}))` statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the routes are set up before any other middleware. Move this line:

```
require('./router/main')(app, language, connection, logger);
```

after this:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'pecuniamsekretsession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

in your `server.js`.

Comment: Also, if you don't use router, it's worth checking that you register the endpoints (app.get/app.post) *after* you register the session middleware as any you define before won't work with it.