# Simple Node/Express app not recognizing Session store

Tags: javascript, express, session, redis, express-session

I have an extremely small express app to illustrate a problem I'm having.

I'm using [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) as a session store on my express app. I'm having a problem simply connecting to it though. Simply printing out `req.session.store` results in `undefined` as shown below:

```
const session = require('express-session')
const app = require('express')()
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379
  }),
  secret: 'super-secret-key', // TBD: grab from env
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    secure: !isDev, // require HTTPS in production
  }
}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('**testing**')
  console.log(req.session.store)
  res.send('rendering this text')
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3001')
})
```

---

The output of this is:

```
listening on 3001
**testing**
undefined
```

In the `store` property, I've tried connecting via the `url` property and the `client` property in addition to the current `host` and `port` method.

I'm not seeing any errors either so I'm not sure why the `store` is always undefined.

What am I missing with this?

*also*, I did start redis using `redis-server` and I am able to connect to it through other clients

---

**Update 1**
Also, I did look at [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10239147/6365534) which some found useful.
The issue is, from version `1.5>` of `express-session`, it says you don't need the [`cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) module, so I don't believe that's the issue.

Comment: Any reason you're expecting a `store` property? I don't see it in the documentation. From what I can see, your store is stored under the `session` property itself. Is `req.session` defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`req.session` will only be having properties that are set to the session, you have never set a session property named `store`. below is an example code of a working RedisStore sessions

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: '127.0.0.1', 
  port: 6379
});
client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
client.on('connect', function (err) {
  console.log('connected to redis successfully');
});

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({client: client}),
  secret: 'super-secret-key',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    ttl: 30 * 10000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  client.get('user', (err, data) => {
    console.log('data in redis:', data)
  });
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.redirect('/')
  } else {
    client.set('user', JSON.stringify({username: 'Adeeb'}))
  }
  res.send('login');
})

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.send('logout');
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('server running on port 3001')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comment, there is no native `store` property on the `req.session` object. The `connect-redis` object inherits from `express-session`, so you should add properties to the `req.session` object to hold your state store as shown below:

```
const session = require('express-session')
const app = require('express')()
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379
  }),
  secret: 'super-secret-key', // TBD: grab from env
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    secure: !isDev, // require HTTPS in production
  }
}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('**testing**')
  console.log(req.session)
  console.log(req.session.id)
  res.send('rendering this text')
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Session ID: ${req.session.id}`)
  req.session.userId = 1
  res.redirect('/home')
})

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.userId) {
    res.send(`You are officially logged in. Your session will expire at ${req.session.cookie.expires}`)
  } else {
    res.redirect('/expired')
  }
})

app.get('/expired', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Oops. This session has expired')
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3001')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the session store global, use it in the app.use(session

app.use the global variable

```
var store = new RedisStore({
host: 'localhost',
port: 6379
})

app.use(session({
store ,
secret: 'super-secret-key', // TBD: grab from env
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
cookie: {
 maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
 secure: !isDev, // require HTTPS in production
}
}))

app.use((req,res)=>{
req.session.store=store
})
```